# Inferential methods on large panel data with sparse clusters and rare outcomes

Tags: survival, epidemiology, inference, panel-data

Using longitudinal survey data on children using psychotropic medications, we are interested in estimating associations with medication classes, their persistence and adherence (longitudinal exposures), and certain rare outcomes such as suicidal idealization. There are clusters defined at the child level with no cluster having more than three repeated measures, most clusters have only one observation. There is left truncation of child observations relative to their starting specific drugs and significant recall bias in their self-reported "start date".

What statistical methods would be appropriate for estimating the relative rates of rare outcomes in this cohort? A couple designs come to mind:

1. Conditional logistic regression with propensity (baseline-risk) matched case-control design: Use time as a stratification factor and estimate a med-class time interaction
2. Nested case-control: similar design, match based on risk at baseline, but use survival methods for time-to-event analysis.

The problem with 1 is that I am not sure if adjustment appropriately accounts for confounding due to time. Some kids may be asymptomatic because of their adherence (or, conversely, adhered to meds because they were asymptomatic) so potentially high risk kids are identified as low risk due to successful treatment over time. The problem with 2 is that we eliminate from risk-sets children who experience the event early and their symptoms reduce over time which is very likely. I don't know nor do I think some time based frailty could/would be appropriate for analysis of this data.